# SQL Server 2008R2 Join One To Many

Tags: sql, function, join, sql-server-2008-r2, aggregate

I have 2 tables, table names are `case` and `party`. Both tables have `case_id`. They have a 1 to many relationship (1 case has several parties). For each case, at least one party has to be marked as the primary party (a yes/no field in the party table). I need to find the cases where NO party has been assigned on a case.

So far, I have this query but it only pulls the parties that are not primary parties on each case – but what I need it to find ONLY cases that have NO primary party designated. (I also have a constraint on the type of cases). I am using SQL Server 2008R2. Thanks in advance for any help!

```
select 
    [case].case_id, [case].case_number, count(party.case_id)as party_count
from 
    party
join 
    [case] on [case].case_id = party.case_id
where 
    [case].case_type_id IN(12,13,15) 
    and party.primary_party = ''
group by 
    [case].case_id, [case].case_number
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select *
from case C
left join P on P.case_id = C.case_id and P.primary_party != ''
where P.case_id is null
```

This selects all cases that do not have an associated non-empty primary party.

As a side note, I would recommend using `null` to represent "no primary party" rather than an empty string.

Comment: This works! Thank you a million times! SIde note - if I query primary_party for null, nothing is returned, so that's why I was using empty strings.

Comment: You're welcome! Re: " if I query primary_party for null, nothing is returned, so that's why I was using empty strings" - Correct, your data will not magically transform. You'd have to change the data type for primary_party to be nullable and have whatever populates that data set it to null rather than an empty string. I was recommending this because the purpose of null is the concept of "no value".

Answer (score 0):

Although your code is a bit confusing a must say (it's not a very good idea to use SQL reserved words as table or field names, or any other objects i must say, even if you put them on brackets)

But here is the thing you need a RIGHT OUTER JOIN.

It should be something like this:

```
SELECT
  C.case_id, 
  C.case_number, 
  COUNT(P.case_id) AS party_count
FROM
  party P
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN [case] C ON 
    C.case_id = p.case_id AND
    C.case_type_id IN (12, 13, 15) 
WHERE 
  P.primary_party = '' AND
  P.case_id IS NULL
GROUP BY
  C.case_id, 
  C.case_number
```

Comment: This database that I have to work with has about 325 tables, and yes a LOT of them use reserved words. Plus, I have no documentation.  It's a nightmare! Thank you for this, I'm going to try this one now.

Comment: 325 tables with no documentation, a lot of reserved words on those 325 table that you have no info on... Ok, i must wish you good luck! Post back if you have any problems! :-)

Comment: I realize I'm not supposed to post a comment like 'thanks' but seriously you two are better than that class at New Horizons I had to sit through....

Comment: Nothing to thank for! I can only say for myself, but in my case, it's just experience talking. I've done a lot of SQL Coding...